# Improving my script output

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i made a little python script which receives a stream of data from an external source and has to print and count it. Here is the function which is supposed to print everything

```
def printer():
    global Datalist
    for value, k in Datalist.items():
        Input1 = k['I1']
        Input2 = k['I2']        

    TOP = sorted(Datalist.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    print '--------------------------------------'
    for value in TOP[0:1]:
        print value
```

The output i get is something like this

```
(u'RESULTS', {'I1': 32, 'I2': 26})
```

Now that i got what i was looking for, i'd like to have it in a "prettier" way: 
I tried to delete any brace and every `'` from the output with `.replace` but Python, of course, won't let me edit tuples. Is there a way to do it?

Second thing i wanted to do was to print the results into a table, for that i thought about pandas, so that i would have been able to organize it better and have "RESULTS" as an index, but i don't know how to put the tuple into a pandas dataframe, is it possible to do this thing?

Comment: So, the question is how to print the object `(u'RESULTS', {'I1': 32, 'I2': 26})` in a pretty syntax of your choice? Give us an example output you'd like to see :)

Comment: Well, first of all i'd like to delete any brace, u', ' and parenthesis so it should be something like: RESULTS: I1: 32 | I2: 26. After that my goal was to print it on a table, i know this could be done on Pandas, but i don't know how to do the same with a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can replace that last print statement with:

```
print 'RESULTS:', # last comma prevents newline
for key,val in value[1]:
   print key+':'+str(val),
print ''          # newline
```

for python3:

```
print('RESULTS:',end='')
for key,val in value[1]:
   print(key+':'+str(val),end='')
print('')         # newline
```

Comment: I got the error 'need more than one value to unpack' when i tried to replace 'print value' with it!

Comment: Try using the python3 syntax, if using python 2 add this to the top of your script: `from __future__ import print_function`